# Want to prove a matrix inequality

Tags: calculus, matrices

There are two matrices $A_{n\times m}$ (which has complex entries) and $B_{n\times n}$ (which is diagonal and each entry is positive). Then I have

$$P=(A^HA)^{-1}A^HBA(A^HA)^{-1}$$ $$Q=(A^HB^{-1}A)^{-1}$$

I want to show that diagonal entries of $P$ are greater than or equal the corresponding diagonal entries in $Q$, i.e., $\{P\}_{i,i}\geq \{Q\}_{i,i}$.

I can show this inequality when $A$ is square matrix, but I am unable to prove when it is a general matrix with $n\times m$.

Comment: What is $R$?  Do you mean $B$?

Comment: Yes, it is a typo. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using notation $> 0$ for positive definite and $\ge 0$ for positive semidefinite. We have

1. $B$ diagonal and $B> 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $B^{-1}>0$.
2. $$
   \left[\matrix{B & A\\A^* & A^*B^{-1}A}\right]=\left[\matrix{B \\A^*}\right]B^{-1}\left[\matrix{B & A}\right]\ge 0.
   $$
3. Taking the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Schur_complement_condition_for_positive_definiteness_and_positive_semidefiniteness):
   $B-A(A^*B^{-1}A)^{-1}A^*\ge 0$.
4. $$
   P-Q=(A^*A)^{-1}A^*\bigl[B-A(A^*B^{-1}A)^{-1}A^*\bigr]A(A^*A)^{-1}\ge 0.
   $$
   Hence, $P_{ii}\ge Q_{ii}$.

Comment: Thanks @A.G. !!! It helps a lot.